# Unable to find Fast Registration Mode to register and login user automatically using fbconnect button

Tags: 6

I read the README.txt from start to finish. 
1. I have enabled the following modules under drupal for facebook.
   1. Facebook API
   2. Facebook Apps
   3. Facebook Connect
   4. FB User Management
2. After That I have added my facebook app using settings page : Add App
3. In FB settings page (admin/build/fb/settings) I have checked the following settings.

- Use Secure URLs:Use HTTPS only when Facebook expects a secure URL. (Recommended.)
- Use FB Cookie
- Store tokens in session
- Use Oauth when initializing javascript.
- Get login status when initializing javascript.
- Use locale learned from facebook, if available.

4. Under user settings (admin/build/fb/fb_user) I have checked the the human friendly name for option:Username Style for Automatically Created Accounts:
5. Now I have logged out and moved the**" facebook connect login "** block on the front page
6. I can see fb login button above login page
7. I clicked on fb login button and I am redirected to facebook site requesting for login details
8. after logging in through facebook I see my facebook profile picture with following message

> NAME , after login or registration your account will be connected.


9.  When I log in using admin (which has different email address then what the fb account has) I get the following warning after successful login **"Failed to get Facebook user info for account 10201963083270364: The underlying FQL query made by this API call has encountered the following error: status is not a member of the user table."**
10.Also no user is created using fb login button. 
11. Also I logout , then use fblogin button it logs me in as admin(I realize that admin account is connected to some other fb account whose email address is different) so ***How Can I deauthorize the facebook account connected and allow other facebook account to be linked to this account?***

11. Next I try to register using fb by navigating to "registration " provided as shown in the point no . 8

I am redirected to user/register which has my profile picture and profile name.

12. While trying to register my email id is not mapped but filling the details creates a new user which is default drupal functionality

13,  Now when I again try to login via fb login I get the same message as in the point 8. So , now I again login using the password added using user/register page to see if my facebook account is linked after login

14. Finally I again logout and try to use the fb login button to login and it connects automatically . So the fb account is linked

The MAIN QUESTION TO ASK-------
**How can I enable FAST REGISTRATION MODE in D6 which onclick of fblogin button automatically registers a new user and logs me in to the account?**

---

Does this module provide some settings for fast registration. Please let me know if there are any modules I need to enable or settings I need to set?